# Convert date as text "YYYY:DD:MM hh:mm:ss" to real date

Tags: excel, date

How can I convert a date given as text "YYYY:DD:MM hh:mm:ss" to a date with format YYYY.MM.DD hh:mm:ss?

Comment: Related https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e#__toc320186182

Comment: Are you looking for VBA solution? At any rate, you will need to parse the string yourself, I am afraid. You need to convert it to a date and then you can format it any way you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The worksheet formula solution would involve the [LEFT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Left-Function-D5897BF6-91F5-4BF8-853A-B63D7DE09681), [MID function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Mid-Function-427E6895-822C-44EE-B34A-564A28F2532C) and [RIGHT function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/RIGHT-function-C838C2BE-1D0A-4E75-A2F5-9512D766E2F6).

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1, 4), MID(A1, 9, 2), MID(A1, 6, 2))+TIME(MID(A1, 12, 2), MID(A1, 15, 2), RIGHT(A1, 2))
```

[image: Date text parsing]

Format the cell (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) with a Numbers ► Custom ► Type: of *yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss*.

Those functions work exactly the same way in VBA. The [DATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/date-function-9b619152-52d4-48f0-b1ab-a32dee59b6e4) and [TIME function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/time-function-125c7e3c-2d9a-4af6-ba61-73d998468e22) would be [DateSerial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx05d0c(v=vs.90).aspx) and [TimeSerial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws25fd2z(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: Many thanks for the elaborate answer!! However, I still wonder why applying the appropiate custom format (Type: of _YYYY:DD:MM hh:mm:ss_) to the text does not suffice to convert it to date? I thought it would, since I'm explicitly telling Excel which string elements refer to year, month, etc.

Comment: @Kay - The current custom format mask is not considered when Excel tries to 'intelligently' convert text-based datetimes to actual datetimes. As noted in another offered answer, there is also the regional *m/d/yy* vs *d/m/yy* to consider. Is 2015:04:07 07-Apr-2015 or 04-Jul-2015? On the wrong regional system half of the entries may convert to the wrong dates and the other half not convert at all. It is best to definitively parse each piece and construct both the date and time elements then stitch them together.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and my file has 400,000+ rows with text in this format : yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. The custom date format did not work at first, but you can use =VALUE(text) and then apply the custom cell format of your choice. Somehow Excel knows your text is a date with an equivalent number butwill not let you change the format otherwise.